# Data Conversion from one class type to another class type

Tags: c++, oop

I was trying to convert one class type data to another class type therefore I was using casting operator method in my oops program in c++.

```
class example2;
class example1
{
   int id;
   int numbers;
   int cost;
public:
   example1(int a, int b, int c)
   {
     id=a;
     numbers=b;
     cost=c;
   }

// getid() added here
// getnumber() added here
// getcost() added here

   operator example2()
   {
    example2 temp;
    temp.id=id;
    temp.value=numbers*cost;
    return temp;
   }
};
class example2
{
   int id;
   int value;
public:
   example2(int x,int y){
     id=x;
     value=y;
   }
  void display(){
    cout<<"id "<<id<<endl;
    cout<<"value "<<value<<endl;
  }
};
```

when I was using casting from example1 to example2. It is showing error.

```
int main()
{
  example1 s1(100,5,140.0);
  example2 s2;
  s2=s1;
  s2.display();
  return 0;
}
```

it is giving error but why?. I made an operator overloading member function in example1 class because object of example1 has to be changed into object of example2.So this function invoked from class example1's method only which I think.It should be correct

Error was like:

**error: return type 'class example2' is incomplete and 
example2 temp; has incomplete type**

Somehow I resolved this in another way I added a constructor in example2 class side:

```
example2(example1 e)
{
  id=e.getid(); //these functions already added in my code i didnt mentioned them in here.
  value=e.getnumber()*e.getcost();
}
```

and make comment of 'operator example2()' part in example1.
now it is working.
But previous way was not accepting. Please help me to correct me in my previous way of doing this thing.

Comment: The error message is telling you that you need more than just a forward declaration of `example2` at the time you have `example1` in the code.

Comment: I don't see a single cast anywhere in that program.

Comment: It is casting from one class type data to another class type data.I used it from s2=s1.

Comment: I want this problem solved from only class to class operator which does not take any parameter and does not return anything

Comment: No, s2=s1 is just assigning, trying to stuff s1 into s2 and that may or mnay not work depending on the types of s2 and s1. A cast temporarily changes the data type, allowing you to treat example2 like an example1 and  in this case will end in disaster as there is no relationship between example2 and example1.

Comment: s2=s1 is assigning but it is calling member function "operator example2() "because s1 is example1 object and I am assigning it in example2 object s2.which is like example2 s2=example2(s1); or  example2 s2=s1; here operator will be invoked by s1

Comment: No it's not. s2=s1 is calling the equals operator. If you want call your cast overload, and you don't, it would be done like this: `(example2)s1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the classes must be defined first and the second cannot fully be used until after it is defined. This means you have to break up the class definitions a bit.

Here is an example of how to get at the class that's not yet defined, based off of the OP's post. Explanation comes in the form of comments embedded in the code to keep the code all in one cut-n-pasteable chunk.

```
#include <iostream>
class example2; // forward declaration to satisfy compiler until example2
                // is defined
class example1
{
    int id;
    int numbers;
    int cost;
public:
    example1(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        id = a;
        numbers = b;
        cost = c;
    }

    example1(const example2 & e)  // the const and reference are just because
                                  // no point copying e, and const ensures no
                                  // side effects to e
    {
        *this = e;  // why duplicate code? Just calling operator=
    }

    example1& operator=(const example2 & e);
        // note the lack of an implementation. This is because at this point
        // the compiler only knows example2 exists, but not what it looks
        // like. Can't copy what what you haven't seen.

    int getid() const //const to allow me to use const references.
    {
        return id;
    }
    int getnumber() const
    {
        return numbers;
    }
    int getcost() const
    {
        return cost;
    }
    void display()
    {
        std::cout << "Example 1" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "id " << id << std::endl;
        std::cout << "numbers " << numbers << std::endl;
        std::cout << "cost " << cost << std::endl;
    }

};

class example2
{
    int id;
    int value;
public:
    example2(int x, int y)
    {
        id = x;
        value = y;
    }
    example2(const example1 &e)
    {
        *this = e;  // once again just calls the equals operator
    }

    example2 & operator=(const example1 & e) // OK. This time we know what
                                             // example1 looks like and can
                                             // actually implement the method
    {
        id = e.getid();
        value = e.getnumber() * e.getcost();
        return *this;
    }

    int getid() const
    {
        return id;
    }
    int getvalue()const
    {
        return value;
    }
    void display()
    {
        std::cout << "Example 2" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "id " << id << std::endl;
        std::cout << "value " << value << std::endl;
    }
};

// and now for the implementation of example1's equals operator
example1& example1::operator=(const example2 & e)
{
    id = e.getid();
    numbers = -1; //do real work to get cost and numbers from e.getvalue()
    cost = -1;
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    example1 s1(100, 5, 140.0);
    example2 s2(1, 2);
    s2 = s1;
    s2.display();
    example2 s3(314, 278);
    s1 = s3;
    s1.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Now for overloading the cast operator. This is something you almost never want to do because there are almost always much more obvious ways to accomplish the same goal.

For example:

```
#include<iostream>

class Integer
{
public:
    Integer(int val):mVal(val)
    {
    }
    operator int()
    {
        return mVal;
    }
    int getVal()
    {
        return mVal;
    }
private:
    int mVal;
};

int main()
{
    Integer t(42);
    int x = (int)t; // We're turning the Integer into an int? Kinda makes sense.
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
    x = t.getVal(); // hey! we're getting the integer's value! Do I need this comment?
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class example2;
class example1(){
   operator example2()
   {
       example2 temp;
       //more stuff
   }
};
```

At this point in time in the code the full definition of `example2` must be known to the compiler because you are creating an instance of this class called `temp`. However you only have a forwards declaration of `example2` at this point in time. So while the compiler knows that `example2` is a type because of the forwards declaration it doesn't have the full information about the class at that point in time so it is unable to make `temp`. This is giving you the error you see.

If what you want to do here is be able to assign to `example2`s from types of `example1`s you should create an assignment operator for `example2` that takes `example1`s.

```
class example2{
    example2& operator= (example1 const& e1){
        this->id = e1.id;
        this->value = e1.numbers * e1.cost;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

However this strikes me as a bad design, there's probably better ways of achieving what you want that involves a different design. For example a method that's purpose is to take an `example1` as a parameter and modify the state would be a lot clearer than this. As would just constructing a new `example2` from the information in the `example1`

Comment: then how can i use 'operator example2()' member method to convert example1 data into example2 type data.

Comment: should i use inheritance concept?

Comment: shuttle You did that using assignment operator from copy tha data from example1 to example2 that I have done and i have already mentioned that i have solved my problem using example2(example1 e)
{
  id=e.getid();
  value=e.getnumber()*e.getcost();
} I want it from example1 class using class to class operator not assignment operator.

Comment: What I have suggested here is to overload the assignment operator, what you did was to make a conversion. The first part of the answer explains how to fix the issue with your constructor that does the conversion, make sure the entire class is defined before this point, you need more than just a forward declaration.

Comment: if i am defining example2 class before example1. it still giving error.can you give me conversion solution.Whatever you want to say, please help me to write the design for that

Answer (score 0):

You have to use return type example2 then it will work

Comment: which functions or method should be return example2? could you give more detail?

Comment: please provide detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

it just worked fine, let me know if i am missing something..
i think things you were missing are:

1. definition of class example2 before class example1
   2.accessing private data members of example2 through return by referece
   3.empty constructor in destination class example2

   ```
       #include<iostream>
       using namespace std;
       class example2
       {
          int id;
          int value;
       public:
           example2 () {}
          example2(int x,int y){
            id=x;
            value=y;
          }
         void display(){
           cout<<"id "<<id<<endl;
           cout<<"value "<<value<<endl;
         }
         int& getid () // return by reference
         {
             return id;
         }

         int& getvalue () // return by reference
         {
            return value;
         }
       };
       class example1
       {
          int id;
          int numbers;
          int cost;
       public:
          example1(int a, int b, int c)
          {
            id=a;
            numbers=b;
            cost=c;
          }
          operator example2()
          {
           example2 temp;
           temp.getid()=id;
           temp.getvalue()=numbers*cost;
           return temp;
          }
       };
       int main()
       {
         example1 s1(100,5,140.0);
         example2 s2;
         s2=s1;
         s2.display();
         return 0;
       }
   ```